# iOS 5 automatic code execution using StoryBoard

Tags: ios, storyboard, execution

Using StoryBoard, I've created my first view controller with a button.  It segues and opens up a second scene.  The second scene has a button.  You tap the button, it pulls up data.  I don't want to have to tap the button on the second scene to get the data to load.  I would have put it in a viewdidload but it doesn't seem to work.  (Yes, I'm a newb.)  I've created an Objective-C Class called ResultsView and connected it to the scene.  I'm just wanting the second scene to execute a couple of lines of code when it is segued to.  Can you tell me how to get this done?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` should be getting triggered (or did you mean something different when you said it didn't work?). you can also try `viewDidAppear` (or `viewWillAppear` for that matter). you're implementing these in the view controller and not the view, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup for the segue in the prepareforSegue method.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  // Do your stuff to setup the Segue
}
```

And also the view lifecycle APIs will get called.